# How to open a port on unbuntu to other computers hosted through a Node.js program

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, networking, port

I made a program that uses port 312 to transfer data using http but the port seems to only be open to the computer itself

I used `ufw allow 312/tcp` to enable the port

When I tested the command with things like `netstat -ntlup | grep 312` and `nc -vv <SERVER URL> 312` and even `telnet <SERVER IP> 312` all showed the port being open with the outputs of

```
tcp6       0      0 :::312                  :::*                    LISTEN      3871/node
```

```
Connection to <SERVER URL> (<SERVER IP>) 312 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

```
Connected to <SERVER IP>.
```

respectively

The only weird thing I noticed was the netstat record being tcp6 instead of tcp like when i checked ports like 80 used for http as well.

And if it helps, I use the Node.js http built in library, here is my requests code:

```js
const http = require('http');
const https_imp = require('https');

module.exports = {}

module.exports.sendRequest = async (url, data, https) => {
    const options = {
        hostname: url,
        port: 312,
        path: '',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
    };
    var useThis
    if (https) {
      useThis = https_imp
    } else {
      useThis = http
    }
    return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const req = useThis.request(options, (res) => {
            var output = ''
            res.on('data', (d) => {
                output += d.toString()
            })

            res.on('end', () => {
                resolve(output)
            })

            res.on('error', (err) => {
                reject(err)
            })
        })
        req.write(JSON.stringify(data))
        req.end()
    })
}
```

For testing I used both my program and Postman and both timed out

I also know the software itself should work considering I developed and fully tested it on my own machine and it works fine

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you connect to the port if you just make a netcat server?

Comment: No, when trying the through netcat it still times out, but when running netcat with verbose it prints ```Listening on 0.0.0.0 312``` any ideas?

Comment: Then this has nothing to do with nodejs. Can be anything between your host and client machines.